# IBM MQSeries Accessing Issue from .NET

Tags: c#, accessibility, tcp, ibm-mq

I'm not extremely familiar with IBM MQSeries, but I am writing c# scripts which write and read files from my queue server. The problem is my read works but my write doesn't. Please notice that I am using the same queue so don't bother going in that direction.

My code firstly accesses the MQserver with the following code:

```
MQQueueManager qManager;
MQQueue queue;
MQMessage queueMessage;
MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions;

string QueueName;

public MQAccess(string queueName, string queueManager, string connection, string channel)
{
    QueueName = queueName;

    qManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, channel, connection);

    queue = qManager.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
}
```

I am able to read files from my queue with this code:

```
public bool NextMessage(ref string message, ref DateTime putDateTime)
{
    queueMessage = new MQMessage();
    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();

    queueGetMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

    try
    {
        queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
    }
    catch (MQException mqex)
    {
        if (mqex.ReasonCode == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
        {
            message = "";
            return false;
        }
        else
            throw mqex;
    }
    message = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
    putDateTime = queueMessage.PutDateTime;

    if (message.StartsWith("´╗┐"))
    {
        message = message.Substring(3, message.Length - 3);
    }

    return true;
}
```

If I however try to write with the following code it gives me errors:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    queueMessage = new MQMessage();
    queueMessage.WriteString(message);
    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
    queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();

    queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
}
```

My error catch gives me the error:

> Error in the application

Which doesn't show much of course. So I checked the event log on the server and this showed me the error:

> An error occurred receiving data from
>   stx041774 (192.168.225.51) over
>   TCP/IP. This may be due to a
>   communications failure.
>
> The return code from the TCP/IP (recv)
>   call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these
>   values and tell the systems
>   administrator.

I looked up 10054 and means:

> An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to make this work? Is there perhaps an MQC option I have to set for writing? Because I have no idea what to do with the options, I'm not even sure if this is the issue.

Please keep in mind that I also close my connection every time with:

```
public void Close()
{
    queueMessage = null;
    queue.Close();
    qManager.Close();
}

~MQAccess()
{
    queueMessage = null;
    queue.Close();
    qManager.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why your first line is indented differently from the rest? It's very unattractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squig was close but no cigar.  When you open the queue, you need to specify both input *and* output on the open options if you want to both read and write messages.  The example code has only input options specified.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you set your get options when getting messages you also need to set put
options when you put a message

```
queuePutMessageOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
```

is what your missing.

Comment: The put message options are MQPMO_, the open options are MQOO_ and you are mixing the two.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe having a look at this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Chat_Using_MSMQ.aspx), in relation to MSMQ protocol, the article implements a chat system.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This is MSMQ, I'm talking about IBM MQSeries

Comment: @wtfudge: Oh sorry...bummer! maybe it might have been better to edit your question to emphasize IBM MQSeries, not MSMQ...as not to confuse with the two...